# How to replace character in certain column with awk

Tags: bash, awk, replace, str-replace, gawk

Fields in my file awk-test are enclosed in brackets and delimited with semicolon:

```
"col1";"col2";"col3";"col4";"col5";
"eiusmod";"tempor";"incididunt";"ut";"labore";
"et";"dolore";"magna";"aliqua";"Ut";
"enim";"ad";"minim";"veniam";"quis";
"ut";"aliquip";"ex";"ea";"commodo";
"nostrud";"exercitation";"ullamco";"laboris";"nisi";
```

Real data (header line plus three records):

```
"col1";"col2";"col3";"col4";"col5";
"/absence/lang/#LANG_ID#/.descr.php";"BP2_DESCR";"Dodaj";"Add";"Adicionar";
"/cal/lang/#LANG_ID#/cal_feed.php";"LF_COMM_MSG";"je komentiral ""#EVENT_TITLE#""";"commented on an event ""#EVENT_TITLE#""";"comentado sobre o evento ""#EVENT_TITLE#""";
"/mod/lang/#LANG_ID#/set_events.php";"IM_NOTIFY";"Pozdravljeni #USER_NAME#!

#FROM_USER# vam je poslal(a) sporocilo.

------------------------------------------

#FROM_USER#: #MESSAGE#

------------------------------------------;"Hello #USER_NAME#!

You have a new notification from #FROM_USER#

------------------------------------------

#MESSAGE#

------------------------------------------;"OlÃ¡ #USER_NAME#!

VocÃª tem uma nova notificaÃ§Ã£o de #FROM_USER# 

------------------------------------------

 #MESSAGE# 

------------------------------------------;
```

I know how to print first 30 lines of column 3 and 4 if column 3 has character "m":

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS = ";" } ; $3 ~/m/ {print $3 ";" $4} NR==30{exit}' OFS=';' awk-test
```

The result is:

```
"magna";"aliqua"
"minim";"veniam"
"ullamco";"laboris"
```

But I don't know
(a) how to replace "m" with "x" on a test 30 lines sample
(b) how to replace "m" with "x" on a real 250.000 lines file.

Desired output on test-awk:

```
"xagna";"aliqua"
"xinim";"veniam"
"ullaxco";"laboris"
```

In reality I need to fix the errors on characters in column 3 only. Therefore I would like to know  how to write the changed lines and keep the unchanged ones into a new file that will contain fixed column 3?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can your fields contain semi-colons or newlines? If the answer is "no" then why are you enclosing them in quotes?

Comment: This file is not mine, it is a CSV output file I have to deal with. Each field is enclosed in quotes and delimited by semicolon. Semicolon is also on the end of each line. Yes, fields contain also semicolons and newlines.

Comment: Then the answer you accepted won't work for you as it assumes you have neither of those situations. [edit] your question to show some truly representative sample input and output, including semicolons and newlines within fields, if you'd like help.

Comment: I see in addition to semicolons and newlines your fields can also include escaped quotes. Given your updated input you need the solution posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001. Just use `;` instead of `,` in it.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions Ed, but I am quite lost as I am an absolute  beginner. Could you explain the code:
awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) print i, "<" $i ">"}'
and could you answer how can I write the changes as well as unchanged records to new file?

Comment: That script doesn't apply to you - you need the bigger one under it that doesn't use FPAT. `print` will produce output so `awk '{ ... print... }' input > output`. If you do want to learn about FPAT though, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content.

Comment: I will study FPAT. Do I understand correctly: 'awk statement inputFile > outputFile' ? And how to ensure that **all records** are written to the new file, the changed ones as well as the ones that were not altered?

Comment: There's nothing special about changed vs unchanged records. When a `print` executes it outputs the current record whether it's been changed or not. Not sure I understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156701/discussion-between-andrej-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk solution:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
NR>1 && sub(/m/,"x",$3){print $3, $4}
```

This will work on your *real* 250.000 lines file:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"xagna";"aliqua"
"xinim";"veniam"
"ullaxco";"laboris
```

or, with a one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR>1 && sub(/m/,"x",$3){print $3, $4}' file
```

Comment: no need to check $3 contains m, sub will just fail if it doesn't

Comment: Sure. I misread the question myself: lines having no `m` in $3 should not be printed. You can solve this putting the sub as condition in an `if` as well.

Comment: You can just do `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} NR>1 && sub(/m/,"x",$3){print $3, $4}'`

Comment: And that's even more concise. +1.